# Convergent sequence: If $\lim a_n\ne0$ then $|a_n|>\delta$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I prove that if $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n \neq 0 $ then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\delta >0$ such that $|a_n| > \delta $ for all $n > n_0$. Please help me.

Comment: This is only true if the limit is positive.

Answer (score 4):

The right statement should be: there exists an $n_0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|a_n| > \delta$ for all $n >n_0$. As stated, the result is false for many negative sequences.

Proof: Assume by contradiction this is not true. Then, for each 
$\epsilon>0$ and each $N$, there exists some $n$ so that 
$$|a_n| < \epsilon$$

Now, use the definition of a Cauchy sequence to deduce that your sequence converges to $0$.

**P.S.** When we assume by contradiction that this is not true, we actually (can) get a subsequence of $a_n$ which converges to $0$. If you are familiar with the fact that any Cauchy sequence which has a convergent subsequence must converge to the same limit, the proof becomes shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$. As $\ell\ne0$, if $\varepsilon>0$ is small enough, the interval $(\ell-\varepsilon,\ell+\varepsilon)$ will not contain $0$ (you may choose $\varepsilon=\dfrac{\lvert\ell\rvert}2$, for instance).

Now since the sequence converges to $\ell$, there exists a $n_0\in\mathbf N$ such that $a_n\in(\ell-\varepsilon,\ell+\varepsilon)$, hence $a_n>\ell-\varepsilon>0\;$ (if $\ell>0$), or  $a_n<\ell+\varepsilon<0\;$ (if $\ell<0$), for all $n\ge n_0$.

Comment: And why the limit is positive? This is not assumed anywhere.

Comment: I forgot to write that case… Thanks for pointing it.